# How can I compute an md5sum on Macintosh OSX Lion?

Tags: osx-lion, md5sum

How can I compute an md5sum on Macintosh OSX Lion?  Is it built in to the OS or do I need to download an application?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the command prompt:

```
md5 <filename>
```